# Track Link Clicks Using Cookies, PHP

Tags: php, cookies, hyperlink

Does anyone *know* how to track the number of times a user clicks on a link using cookies on PHP? I'd like to be able to have a user log-in using PHP simple without a database but only using cookies for educational purposes.

```
// Form in HTML

name: _____________
email: ____________
                SUBMIT

// After submit, variables $_POST['name'] and $_POST['email'] collect 
// Info, records it on COOKIES

// Echo sentence saying: here's your link **which downloads a PDF**

// The click event is recorded as well to make sure that I allow user to click on it once
```

Do you guys have any inputs on this using cookies and PHP only? No database, no session, no security concerns, no program design sarcasm please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a link that is taking the user away from your app, then you will have to use jquery and add a onclick listner to that particular link and have ajax run a counter from a backend php page.
If you the link simply takes the user in to another page of the app, you can have some thing like

```
$counter = $_COOKIE["cookie_name"];
$counter++;
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("cookie_name", $counter, $expire);
```